# Information about the time remaining won't appear. Why?

Tags: javascript, battery

The HTML5 Battery Status API (Remake, code shown below) has a problem. The time left (until the battery runs out) is not showing up. I tried copying the JavaScript from the original project on CodePen. This did not work. I checked the code and found nothing wrong. No errors were displayed.
Original: https://codepen.io/lnfnunes/pen/mEZzBa
CodePen

The Code is shown below.

```js
const $batteryInfo = document.querySelector('.battery-manager .info');
const $charging = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-charging');
const $level = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-level');
const $remaining = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-remaining');

const $battery = document.querySelector('.battery-manager .battery');
const $batteryLevel = $battery.querySelector('.level');

navigator.getBattery()
  .then(function(battery) {
    (function init() {
      updateChargeInfo();
      updateLevelInfo();
      updateDischargingInfo();

      battery.addEventListener('chargingchange', updateChargeInfo);
      battery.addEventListener('levelchange', updateLevelInfo);
      battery.addEventListener('dischargingtimechange', updateDischargingInfo);
    }());

    function updateChargeInfo() {
      let $value = $charging.querySelector('.value');
      $value.innerHTML = (battery.charging ? 'Plugged IN, charging...' : 'Plugged OUT, not charging!');
      
      $battery.classList.remove('battery--is-plugged');
      if (battery.charging) {
        $battery.classList.add('battery--is-plugged');
      }
    }
    function updateLevelInfo() {
      let $value = $level.querySelector('.value');
      let perc = battery.level * 100;
      $value.innerHTML = (perc.toFixed(0) + '%');

      let percStep = perc - perc % 1;
  $batteryLevel.classList.add('level--' + percStep);
    }
    function updateDischargingInfo() {
      let $value = $remaining.querySelector('.value-time');
      $value.innerHTML = ~~battery.dischargingTime > 0 ? moment.duration(battery.dischargingTime, 'seconds')
                               .format('h[h] m[m]') : '--';
    }
  }
);
```

```css
h1, div {
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.battery-manager {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.battery-manager > .info {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.battery {
  position: relative;
  width: 156px;
  height: 72px;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.battery:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -16.6px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #ffffff;
  clip: rect(0, 36px, 36px, 23.4px);
  border-radius: 0%;
}
.battery > .level {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
.battery > .level--0 {
  width: 0%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--1 {
  width: 1%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--2 {
  width: 2%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--3 {
  width: 3%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--4 {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--5 {
  width: 5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--6 {
  width: 6%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--7 {
  width: 7%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--8 {
  width: 8%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--9 {
  width: 9%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--10 {
  width: 10%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--11 {
  width: 11%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--12 {
  width: 12%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--13 {
  width: 13%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--14 {
  width: 14%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}
.battery > .level--15 {
  width: 15%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
  background-color: #ff5722;
}
.battery > .level--16 {
  width: 16%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--17 {
  width: 17%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--18 {
  width: 18%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--19 {
  width: 19%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--20 {
  width: 20%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--21 {
  width: 21%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--22 {
  width: 22%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--23 {
  width: 23%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--24 {
  width: 24%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--25 {
  width: 25%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--26 {
  width: 26%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--27 {
  width: 27%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--28 {
  width: 28%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--29 {
  width: 29%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--30 {
  width: 30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--31 {
  width: 31%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--32 {
  width: 32%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--33 {
  width: 33%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--34 {
  width: 34%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--35 {
  width: 35%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--36 {
  width: 36%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--37 {
  width: 37%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--38 {
  width: 38%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--39 {
  width: 39%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--40 {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--41 {
  width: 41%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--42 {
  width: 42%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--43 {
  width: 43%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--44 {
  width: 44%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--45 {
  width: 45%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--46 {
  width: 46%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--47 {
  width: 47%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--48 {
  width: 48%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--49 {
  width: 49%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,#bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}
.battery > .level--50 {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--51 {
  width: 51%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--52 {
  width: 52%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--53 {
  width: 53%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--54 {
  width: 54%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--55 {
  width: 55%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--56 {
  width: 56%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--57 {
  width: 57%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--58 {
  width: 58%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--59 {
  width: 59%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--60 {
  width: 60%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--61 {
  width: 61%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--62 {
  width: 62%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--63 {
  width: 63%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--64 {
  width: 64%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--65 {
  width: 65%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--66 {
  width: 66%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--67 {
  width: 67%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--68 {
  width: 68%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--69 {
  width: 69%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--70 {
  width: 70%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--71 {
  width: 71%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--72 {
  width: 72%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--73 {
  width: 73%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--74 {
  width: 74%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--75 {
  width: 75%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--76 {
  width: 76%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--77 {
  width: 77%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--78 {
  width: 78%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--79 {
  width: 79%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--80 {
  width: 80%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--81 {
  width: 81%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--82 {
  width: 82%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--83 {
  width: 83%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--84 {
  width: 84%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--85 {
  width: 85%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--86 {
  width: 86%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--87 {
  width: 87%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--88 {
  width: 88%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--89 {
  width: 89%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--90 {
  width: 90%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--91 {
  width: 91%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--92 {
  width: 92%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--93 {
  width: 93%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--94 {
  width: 94%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--95 {
  width: 95%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--96 {
  width: 96%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--97 {
  width: 97%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--98 {
  width: 98%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--99 {
  width: 99%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .level--100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}
.battery > .bolt, .battery > .bolt--border {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 24px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(27deg);
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}
.battery > .bolt:after, .battery > .bolt--border:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 24px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
}
.battery--is-plugged .bolt,
.battery--is-plugged .bolt--border {
  display: block;
}
.select {
  color: #ffa900;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="#232323">
<h1>Battery</h1>

<div class="battery-manager">
  <div class="info">
    <div class="battery-charging"> <span class="value">
</span>
    </div>
    <div class="battery-since-full-charge">

</div>
    <div class="battery-level">
      Battery Level: <span class="value"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="battery-remaining">
      Remaining time until battery runs out: <span class="value-time"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="battery">
    <div class="level"></div>
    <div class="bolt--border"></div>
    <div class="bolt"></div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if your [browser](https://caniuse.com/battery-status) supports it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code. Use `console.log(battery)` and you'll see that `dischargingTime` is `Infinity`. The Battery API may not be able to get this information from the OS.

Comment: @Barmar: Probably when the device is plugged. The ` || 0` catches it. -- There was a code issue regarding moment. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Good point, although it also has `Infinity` for charging time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about [moment durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) for this.
As stated:

> Durations do not have a defined beginning and end date. They are contextless.

and

> It is much better to use moment#diff for calculating days or years between two moments than to use Durations.

**Now in YOUR case.**
It is much better to set a new moment object, force its time to midnight (00:00) and add the `battery.dischargingTime` (seconds) to it.
Then format it to a string.

With the below solution, I got this on Windows 11 - Chrome 104 - Asus GL504G
And thanks for the question, I will use that nice code too ;)

Unplugged device:
[image]

Plugged device:
[image]

```js
const $batteryInfo = document.querySelector('.battery-manager .info');
const $charging = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-charging');
const $level = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-level');
const $remaining = $batteryInfo.querySelector('.battery-remaining');

const $battery = document.querySelector('.battery-manager .battery');
const $batteryLevel = $battery.querySelector('.level');

navigator.getBattery()
  .then(function(battery) {
    (function init() {
      updateChargeInfo();
      updateLevelInfo();
      updateDischargingInfo();

      battery.addEventListener('chargingchange', updateChargeInfo);
      battery.addEventListener('levelchange', updateLevelInfo);
      battery.addEventListener('dischargingtimechange', updateDischargingInfo);
    }());

    function updateChargeInfo() {
      let $value = $charging.querySelector('.value');
      $value.innerHTML = (battery.charging ? 'Plugged IN, charging...' : 'Plugged OUT, not charging!');

      $battery.classList.remove('battery--is-plugged');
      if (battery.charging) {
        $battery.classList.add('battery--is-plugged');
      }
    }

    function updateLevelInfo() {
      let $value = $level.querySelector('.value');
      let perc = battery.level * 100;
      $value.innerHTML = (perc.toFixed(0) + '%');

      let percStep = perc - perc % 1;
      $batteryLevel.classList.add('level--' + percStep);
    }

    function updateDischargingInfo() {
      let $value = $remaining.querySelector('.value-time');
      let dischargingTime = ~~battery.dischargingTime || 0;
      console.log("dischargingTime in seconds:", dischargingTime);

      // Use a new moment object.
      // Set its time to midnight (00:00)
      // Then add the seconds from the battery information
      // And finally... Format it to be displayed.
      let formattedTime = moment()
        .set("hour", 0)
        .set("minute", 0)
        .add(dischargingTime, "seconds")
        .format("HH:mm");
      console.log("formattedTime", formattedTime);

      $value.innerHTML = formattedTime;
    }
  });
```

```css
.as-console * {
  color: black !important;
}

h1,
div {
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.battery-manager {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.battery-manager>.info {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.battery {
  position: relative;
  width: 156px;
  height: 72px;
  border: 4px solid #ffffff;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.battery:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: -16.6px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  background: #ffffff;
  clip: rect(0, 36px, 36px, 23.4px);
  border-radius: 0%;
}

.battery>.level {
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.battery>.level--0 {
  width: 0%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--1 {
  width: 1%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--2 {
  width: 2%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--3 {
  width: 3%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--4 {
  width: 4%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--5 {
  width: 5%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--6 {
  width: 6%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--7 {
  width: 7%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--8 {
  width: 8%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--9 {
  width: 9%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--10 {
  width: 10%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--11 {
  width: 11%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--12 {
  width: 12%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--13 {
  width: 13%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--14 {
  width: 14%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
}

.battery>.level--15 {
  width: 15%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #cf1500, #e61700);
  background-color: #ff5722;
}

.battery>.level--16 {
  width: 16%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--17 {
  width: 17%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--18 {
  width: 18%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--19 {
  width: 19%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--20 {
  width: 20%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--21 {
  width: 21%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--22 {
  width: 22%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--23 {
  width: 23%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--24 {
  width: 24%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--25 {
  width: 25%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--26 {
  width: 26%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--27 {
  width: 27%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--28 {
  width: 28%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--29 {
  width: 29%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--30 {
  width: 30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--31 {
  width: 31%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--32 {
  width: 32%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--33 {
  width: 33%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--34 {
  width: 34%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--35 {
  width: 35%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--36 {
  width: 36%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--37 {
  width: 37%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--38 {
  width: 38%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--39 {
  width: 39%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--40 {
  width: 40%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--41 {
  width: 41%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--42 {
  width: 42%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--43 {
  width: 43%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--44 {
  width: 44%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--45 {
  width: 45%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--46 {
  width: 46%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--47 {
  width: 47%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--48 {
  width: 48%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--49 {
  width: 49%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #bfbfbf, #a1a1a1);
}

.battery>.level--50 {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--51 {
  width: 51%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--52 {
  width: 52%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--53 {
  width: 53%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--54 {
  width: 54%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--55 {
  width: 55%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--56 {
  width: 56%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--57 {
  width: 57%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--58 {
  width: 58%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--59 {
  width: 59%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--60 {
  width: 60%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--61 {
  width: 61%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--62 {
  width: 62%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--63 {
  width: 63%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--64 {
  width: 64%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--65 {
  width: 65%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--66 {
  width: 66%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--67 {
  width: 67%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--68 {
  width: 68%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--69 {
  width: 69%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--70 {
  width: 70%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--71 {
  width: 71%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--72 {
  width: 72%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--73 {
  width: 73%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--74 {
  width: 74%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--75 {
  width: 75%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--76 {
  width: 76%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--77 {
  width: 77%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--78 {
  width: 78%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--79 {
  width: 79%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--80 {
  width: 80%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--81 {
  width: 81%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--82 {
  width: 82%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--83 {
  width: 83%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--84 {
  width: 84%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--85 {
  width: 85%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--86 {
  width: 86%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--87 {
  width: 87%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--88 {
  width: 88%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--89 {
  width: 89%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--90 {
  width: 90%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--91 {
  width: 91%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--92 {
  width: 92%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--93 {
  width: 93%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--94 {
  width: 94%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--95 {
  width: 95%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--96 {
  width: 96%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--97 {
  width: 97%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--98 {
  width: 98%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--99 {
  width: 99%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.level--100 {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #3ec93e, #43d943);
}

.battery>.bolt,
.battery>.bolt--border {
  display: none;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 24px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotateZ(27deg);
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
}

.battery>.bolt:after,
.battery>.bolt--border:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 24px solid #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
}

.battery--is-plugged .bolt,
.battery--is-plugged .bolt--border {
  display: block;
}

.select {
  color: #ffa900;
  background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<body bgcolor="#232323">
  <h1>Battery</h1>

  <div class="battery-manager">
    <div class="info">
      <div class="battery-charging"> <span class="value">
</span>
      </div>
      <div class="battery-since-full-charge">

      </div>
      <div class="battery-level">
        Battery Level: <span class="value"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="battery-remaining">
        Remaining time until battery runs out: <span class="value-time"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="battery">
      <div class="level"></div>
      <div class="bolt--border"></div>
      <div class="bolt"></div>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

--
Just for this demo notes:

- Added the moment lib which was missing
- Added a CSS rule to restore the snippets's console text color that was messed.